# CSS - How to set right attribute of an element to a body with min-width?

Tags: html, css

I have an element with id "div1", and in CSS:

```
body {
    min-width:50em;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#div1 {
    position:absolute;
    right:20em;
}
```

and if I resize the window til the width of window is less than the min-width of the body, the right side of div1 is still 20em towards the right side of window rather than the right side of the body.

Comment: "min-witdh:50em;" should be "width", just in case you missed the typo.

Comment: position:relative to the body

Comment: @David Thanks. And it is just a typo in my question, but not in my code.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It doesn't work

Comment: show us the full code so we can see it doesn't work

Comment: For me, the only time `right` and `bottom` works is if the element you're trying to move has either absolute or fixed position.

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out that if I add a global container, which means

```
<body>
<div id="global_container">
...
</div>
</body>
```

And in CSS, set the global_container's position as relative, then I can get the right to be right.
But I don't think this way is the standard way to this problem.

Comment: Yeah, actually. Usually, don't use `body` as an element within the page. If you need that, use a container.

Comment: I would think this is exactly how it should be done. It's how _wrappers_ with `min-width` operate